# Load your custom classes in MODx Revolution

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I am trying to make some simple class in MODx but always getting 500 Server error, this ie example.

I created **Plugin** and call it on **webPageinit**

**Plugin**

```
class Foo {
    function HelloWorld() {
       echo 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

And then created **Snippet** and try this

**Snippet**

```
$foo = new Foo;
```

But I am getting internal server error 500, is this proper way to do this, or there is some autolader for your custom class?

Answer (score 1):

I think this documentation can give you deeper explanation, especially about making custom back-end programming.

https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/case-studies-and-tutorials/developing-an-extra-in-modx-revolution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a class inside of MODX, you could load it by $modx->loadClass once. I won't use a plugin to load the class.